# Enable/Disable textboxes using checkbox inside the table

Tags: javascript, php

Help me. I have problem with the code:

I have this script:

```
<script>
$('td input[type="checkbox"]').onclick(function () {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').prop('disable', !this.checked);
}).change();
</script>
```

And the table:

```
       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>#</th>
                                    <th>Activity Name</th>
                                    <th>SkillsID</th>
                                    <th>Percentage</th>
                                    <th><center>Time Estimate Overhead (min)</center>                             </th>
                                    <th><center>Time Estimate Per Unit (min)</center></th>
                                    <th><center>Total Time (min)</center></th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>    
                                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="others1">
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>Preparation</td>
                                    <td class="center">1,7,8</td>
                                    <td class="center"></td>
                                    <td class="center"><input type="text" id="cb1_teo_text" name="cb1_teo_text" style="width: 100%;" disabled=""></td>
                                    <td class="center"><input type="text" id="cb1_tep_text" name="cb1_tep_text" style="width: 100%;" disabled=""></td>
                                    <td class="center"><span id="totaTime1"/></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" name="others2"></td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>Review of Materials</td>
                                <td class="center">1,7,8</td>
                                <td class="center"></td>
                                <td class="center"><input type="text" name="cb2_teo_text" style="width: 100%;" disabled=""></td>
                                <td class="center"><input type="text" name="cb2_tep_text" style="width: 100%;" disabled=""></td>
                                <td class="center"></td>
                            </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

I just want to enable the preceding  with two  when the checkbox is checked and disable when the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Shouldn't it be disabled and not disable?

Comment: At first the textboxes are disable but when the checkbox is checked it should be enable. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.onclick()` event binding in jQuery - it is `.click()`, also the property name to enable and disable elements is `disabled` not `disable`. You also need to wrap the binding in a `$(document).ready()` block so the Javascript isn't trying to bind the event to an element that doesn't exist yet.

These changes to your code are all that are needed to make it work.

```
$(document).ready()
{
    $('td input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    }).change();
});
```

Here is a [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3RRLP/2/) showing the changes.

Comment: @user3326074 I've updated my answer with what I assume will fix the problem, since you didn't actually show any more code.

Comment: I'm sorry. I already figure out the problem. Thanks again.:) Can you help me with the another problem.

Comment: If my answer was correct please mark it as accepted. If my answer wasn't correct please create your own answer and mark it as accepted. If you have another question then please post it as a new question instead of discussing it here.

Comment: this is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923841/apply-autocompute-in-textboxes for another question.

Comment: OK, you've already asked it. I will undo the changes you've made here.

Comment: Thanks! the edited code not display, you should refer on this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21923841/apply-autocompute-in-textboxes